# What is the Best way to post each pictures uploaded separately and automatically?

Tags: images, automation

I have a lot of pictures which I should upload them to my website everyday (about 100 pictures per day). These pictures are uploaded to the website with a Title and a specified little Description. Doing this work is really hard.

**So the question is**:
What is the best and fastest way to do it?
I think one of the best ways is using a Excel file which have a Title, Description and a picture URL column and a plugin which reads the data from this excel file and post them automatically. and of course, the uploading process would be manually.

Comment: As you have already seen with your previously asked questions: Plugin recommendations are off topic. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and take your time to read what's off topic in the [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @kaiser apologize. I edited my question so I'm not asking for a plugin anymore and I just want the best method (not plugin) for doing this. Is it OK now?